# Context processor in forms.py

Tags: python, django, forms

**context_processor.py:**

```
def max_min(request):
    """
    some code. request required, because I need 
    calculate some information about each user
    """
    return {'max': max, 'min':max}
```

**forms.py:**

```
class MaxMin(forms.Form):
my_field = forms.IntegerField( 
   min_value=min, max_value=max, required=True, 
   widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 
   'required': 'true'}))
```

So, I have code in **context_processor.py** (it uses on all pages of site), that I want use in my **forms.py**. But I dont know, how to import and use it. **max_min** needs request, but in **forms.py** I dont have it.

Yes, I know, I can use `{{min}}` and `{{max}}` in forms html, without **forms.py**, but then I need to check in code, whats values I got through POST.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

```
class MAxMin(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, req, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MAxMin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.request = req
    def mymethod(self): 
        return max_min(self.request)
    my_field = forms.IntegerField( 
         min_value=mymethod(), required=True, 
         widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 
         'required': 'true'}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about injecting request at the time of instantiation?

```
#views.py
form = MyForm(request)

#forms.py
def __init__(self, req, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.request = req

#somewhere in your form's body
max_min(self.request)
```

**UPDATE**
Well, your situation appears to be different from what I've expected.
Consider this approach:

```
class MAxMin(forms.Form):
my_field = forms.IntegerField(required=True, 
                              widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 
                              'required': 'true'}))

def __init__(self, req, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MAxMin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['my_field'].min_value = max_min(req)
```

Comment: Careful, by overriding the form `__init__` like that you've disabled the normal parameters (data, initial, etc). You should always accept `*args, **kwargs` and pass them on to the `super` call.

Comment: @AlexParakhnevich I use your code, I have an error: `name 'max_min' is not defined`, then I add `from project.context_processor import max_min`, I have new error: `name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: That's because you're not using it in method's body. Try `mymethod(self): max_min(self.request)`

Comment: @AlexParakhnevich I have updated the post. The same error. May be I have a mistake

Comment: `mymethod() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`

Comment: `name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: @AlexParakhnevich no eerors, but in html no `min_value`

Comment: @AlexParakhnevich it doesnt work, if I use self.fields['my_field'].min_value = 5, for example

Comment: `self.fields['my_field'] = forms.IntegerField(min_value = max_min(req))`